# Ionic + ng-Cordova file transfer with Django

Tags: angularjs, django, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an Ionic hybrid app and one of the features is taking/choosing a picture and uploading it to the server. I found plenty of examples of how to use **$cordovaFileTransfer** plugin. The problem is that my backend is in Django and I don't really understand how to process the upload request from the cordova plugin.
Any help or a small example would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$cordovaFileTransfer` is only the Ionic wrapper for the [cordova file transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). The documentation says:

> The FileTransfer object provides a way to upload files using an HTTP multi-part POST or PUT request, and to download files as well.

Since these are simple http POST requests, you don't need nothing special but only the [Django file uploads documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/) that contains a well documented example.